# When is the next shmita year (as of 5772)?

Tags: calendar, shmita

When is the next shmita year?  Is there disagreement about which year?  If so, which Jewish sects or traditions believe the shmita is in which years?  If you specify years since creation, please also specify the timeline with respect to the Gregorian calendar.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The last shemittah year was Jewish year 5768 (13 Sept 2007 - 29 Sept 2008)

The next few are:

- 5775 (25 Sept 2014 - 13 Sept 2015)
- 5782 (7 Sept 2021 - 25 Sept 2022)
- 5789 (21 Sept 2028 - 9 Sept 2029)

Note that some Rishonim (medieval rabbis) held that the shemittah is the year *prior* to the years mentioned above (See [Tur CM 67](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14271&st=&pgnum=245)) but longstanding normative practice is not according to their view.

Source: I remember when everyone was observing the last Shemittah, and it's every seven years after that. I checked Kaluach regarding the dates for Rosh Hashanna.

Answer (score 0):

Per Pearlman YeC Moshe Emes series for the alignment of Torah testimony, science and ancient civ. volume III 'Bible Chronology, untying a knot'
TALMUD HAS IT RIGHT Holy temple 2 start Shmitta cycle in 3410 anno mundi so 3416 the first Sabbtical. HOLY Temple II end 3830 420 years later a partial year
3829 the last whole year a Sabbatical year. This year 5782 a Sabbatical yr.
5782-2021 (1 Tishrei - Dec 31) = 3761
5782-2022 (1 Jan till month end Elul) = 3760 start Christian era.
3320-3390 anno mundi Jeremiah 70 years Nebuchadnezzar yr. 2 until Cyrus proclamation described in Ezra.
3310 start Shmitta cycle year 1 (3760 -3310 = 451/450 BCE
3314 Ezra arrival yr. 7 of Darius-Artaxerxes b. Achashverosh and Esther.
3316 first Shmitta year (it , like all that follow, is divisible by 7).
3759 last Shmitta year before Christian era. -3761/3760 = 1 Tishrei 2BCE until end Elul 1 BCE
Assume no zero year.
3766 first Shmitta of CE is 1 Tisheri year 5 till end Elul yr. 6.
3829 last Shmitta of Holy Temple II the last full year of Daniel's 70 weeks (490 full years) From mid yr. 68 starting 1 Tishrei until mid yr. 69, month end Elul (the day prior to 1 Tishrei).
5782, this year, a Shmitta year that started 1 Tishrei and will end the day before the coming Roh Hashanna (1 Tishrei) that commemorates the creation of First Adam on literal day 6, the start of 1 anno-mundi. As when The Creator aka G-d of Abraham becomes Sovereign of the Universe, King of Kings, as now has human subjects who alone can serve G-d, via exercising our free will to do so (rather than opting to be in denial).
So mid 2021 till mid 2022 this coming Rosh Hashanah is a Shmitta year.

Comment: It would be helpful to use space to better delineate paragraphs in your answer, and bullets where relevant. This is very hard to read and understand

Answer (score -4):

The shmittah years listed above are wrong.
The timeline has been lost and incorrectly started again.

The shmittah year was celebrated the year that Herod the Great laid siege to Jerusalem, in the year [Siege of Jerusalem (37 BC)]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Jerusalem_%2837_BC%29
"The besieged suffered from lack of provisions, compounded by a famine brought about by the sabbatical year"

The Civil year would have started in the Fall, and would have been 38 to 37 BCE.
The siege started in the spring 37 BCE, and was over before the year was expired, and it was particularly a severe siege since it was also a shmittah year.
This was a 7th shmittah or 49th year, with the following year 37 to 36 BCE being the Jubilee year 79th. www.torahcalendar.com/Calendar.asp?YM=Y-37M7

Now add 50 years for each Jubilee Cycle and you get [14 to 15 CE as the next Jubilee year 80th.]www.torahcalendar.com/Calendar.asp?YM=Y14M7

There is no year zero, so 1BCE to 1 CE is just 1 year.
Add 40 more Jubilee years and you have 2000 more years, and it is [Jubilee year 120, 2014 to 2015 CE.]www.torahcalendar.com/Calendar.asp?PYM=Y2014M7

So .... [2013 to 2014 CE] our present year is:
 Spiritual Year 5999

Civil Year 5999

Year 7 in Shemittah Cycle 7

Creation Shemittah Cycle 840

Year 49 in Jubilee Cycle 120

www.torahcalendar.com/Calendar.asp?PYM=Y2013M7

Comment: Except the Jubilee year hadn't happened since about 600  BCE

Comment: Accepting your (torahcalendar.com) terminus a quo of the fall of 38 B.C., I come up with the fall of 12 A.D. as the beginning of the next shemittah year. The next closest multiple of 49 takes me to the year 2021 and falling back 7 years gives me the fall of 2014 (49 yrs. x 41 = 2009 yrs. + 12 yrs/12A.D. = 2021 - 7 = 2014). this is in agreement with the first answer.

Comment: It's correct that there is no year 0 in the Gregorian calendar, but that doesn't mean that 1 BCE to 1 CE is only one year - it means that 1 BCE **is** 1 CE.