# What are the exact Shmita dates (in Gregorian) since 1900 or a general formula for determining the dates?

Tags: shabbat, calendar, shmita, yovel

I know there are these two questions already (https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36703/trying-to-get-shmita-year-dates-without-a-headache) and ([When is the next shmita year (as of 5772)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13432/when-is-the-next-shmita-year-as-of-5772)); however, they don't appear to provide either a table of date spans or links to one or a general formula for determining the conversion to Gregorian/Western/Christian calendar dates. I couldn't find an exact table of dates only years with a few Google searches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the Jewish year begins on 1 Tishrei and ends on 29 Elul, your question is essentially to translate 1 Tishrei and 29 Elul of every Shmita year into Gregorian.

The Shmita years are those divisible by 7. Since 1900 these years have been:
5663, 5670, 5677, 5684, 5691, 5698, 5705, 5712, 5719, 5726, 5733, 5740, 5747, 5754, 5761, 5768, and 5775 (which began today).

So for each of these, you want to find the Gregorian date for 1 Tishrei and 29 Elul. You can do this using any of a variety of calendar conversion apps and websites, such as http://www.hebcal.com/converter/.

For example, the first Shmita year in the 20th century was 5663, which spanned from 1 Tishrei 5663 = 2 October 1902 to 29 Elul 5663 = 29 September 1903.

Comment: I know this question/answer is about the 20th century, but I was wondering if there was an effect on Shmitta/Hebrew calendar when they dropped 10 days when first starting Gregorian dating in 1582...anyone know?  Or did the Hebrew calendar just stay the same?

Comment: @Gary The Hebrew calendar functions irrelevant of the Gregorian calendar.

Comment: @Gary Unrelatedly, Gregorian dating didn't start everywhere in 1582.

Comment: @Gary. It think you are confusing the Gregorian CALENDAR with the Christian (or "common") ERA.

Comment: I have an off line date converter (Hebrew to civil dates and vice versa). Also, I used an on line converter. Both of these converters give me a date of 21 Sept 1903 = Elul 29 5663 29 Elul 5663 = 29 September 1903 this is the date you give above. The off line converter is Kaluch 3 (Kaluch.org) The on line converter is The Hebrew Calender (http://www.bsswebsite.me.uk/Daysanddates/hebrewdate.htm) I am NOT Hebrew but I do have an interest, particularly the Shemitah years. I wonder if you could help me with discrepancy